# Login Loop and Missing Sidebar - Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: login

I am having issues with Ubuntu. I tried to upgrade to 13.04. I get stuck in a login loop, but I am able to login using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+
<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>. After that, I have to use a short-cut to open the terminal and enter a couple of commands that I found on this site to make the sidebar appear.

It is very cumbersome to have to do this every time I start up Ubuntu. Is there a way to permanently fix these problems?? It's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it once hope it would help you**

**1st Method**

**Try to reconfigure lightdm** (if it doesn't solve your issue then go for *2nd* Method)

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following command:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigre lightdm
  ```
- Then chose `lightdm` from the list. As shown below:

[image: lighdm]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/1378375_454948661291695_937916838_n.jpg))</sub>

- Restart your system:

  ```
  sudo reboot now
  ```

It may fix your issue. If doesn't fix then follow *2nd Method*.

**2nd Method**

Installing a new display manager can fix your problem. Steps to install **GDM**(a display manager much like **lightdm**):

- Open terminal(<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and execute following commands:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gdm
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
  ```

  then chose `gdm` from the list:

[image: gdm]
<sub>(source: [akamaihd.net](https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-prn2/1390653_454948664625028_2140985254_n.jpg))</sub>

```
    sudo reboot
```

- If it's still not fixed, try removing `lightdm` after installing `gdm`:

  ```
  sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm
  sudo reboot
  ```

Hope these methods solve your issue. Reply for further assistance.